# Select multiple HTML elements and edit them at once?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In this [Youtube-Video](https://youtu.be/-mFXqOaqgZk?t=83) (I linked at the relevant time, so one just has to watch like 5 seconds) multiple input elements are selected and edited in one step. How can I do that? Do I need an extension for that?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the person who made the video.

Comment: FYI, "Select multiple HTML (DOM) elements and [modify] them at once" programatically something jQuery excels at.  For example: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/05/jquery-tutorial-how-to-modify-multiple-elements-in-one-line.html

Comment: Flagged as "Close" because the question without the YT link isn't self-explanatory. Please edit it to include either embedded screenshots or describe your end goal in more detail.

Comment: read the docs on `multi cursor`, handy shortcut `Ctrl+D`

Answer (score 0):

Hold down "option / alt" and click / highlight the lines you want to edit. Start typing you will see it work...